# Exclude the values from one specific property from search with ng-model and ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel

Is it possible to exclude a property from search using ng-model and ng-repeat?

You can specify a property and its values like this : ng-model="search.property", but what if I want the search to match all the values **except** the values in one specific property? Does Angular have any solution for this?

This is the filter I am using now :

```
angular.module('app')
.filter("multiText", function ($filter) {
    return function (inputArray, searchText) {

            var wordArray = searchText ? searchText.toLowerCase().split(/\s+/) : [];
            var wordCount = wordArray.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
                inputArray = $filter('filter')(inputArray, wordArray[i]);

            }

            return inputArray;

    };
});
```

Comment: Can you give an example where `search.property` applies? When you say "search", do you mean "filter"? All you have here is `ng-model="something"` - this conveys almost nothing.

Comment: I believe you need to write a custom one.

Comment: @NewDev Yes, filter. I am creating a search bar with text input and using ng-model with it. Then I filter ng-repeat with it. I don´t have the code in front of me right now but something like this : <input type="text" ng-model="search.property">  and <div ng-repeat="object in objects | filter:search">

Comment: You'll need to write your own filter - there is no built-in functionality

Comment: @NewDev I can't seem to find a good solution on how to exclude a property with filter. Do you have any suggestions on where to start or how to approatch it?

Comment: @NewDev Updated my question with code for my filter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter on ng-repeat with ng-model value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996751/filter-on-ng-repeat-with-ng-model-value)