# Filter on ng-repeat with ng-model value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need to filter ng-repeat on value of ng-model
Like this :

```
 <select class="browser-default" ng-model="planning.uuid" id="planning" ng-options="planning.uuid as planning.day for planning in plannings" ng-change="loadRegistration(planning.uuid)">
      <option value="" disabled selected>Planning</option>
 </select>
...
<table...
   <tr ng-repeat="registration in registrations" >
     <td ng-repeat="rate in registration.rate | filter: rate.activity.uuid: planning.activity.uuid">
          {{rate.type.label}}
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My problem is it's seems that the filter `rate.activity.uuid: planning.activity.uuid` doesn't works.

Please what is the good way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your filter to

```
 <td ng-repeat="rate in registration.rate | filter: {activity : {uuid: planning.activity.uuid}} :true">
      {{rate.type.label}}
 </td>
```

Comment: This is essentially strict comparison of expected and actual. Read More : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter